# Access content at alias without redirecting to original content location

Tags: blocks, path-aliases

Is there a way to generate an alias for content WITHOUT having it redirect to the original content location and therefore preserve menu location?

For example - I have one node which is located at http://mysite.com/oranges but I'd also like to access it at http://mysite.com/apples WITHOUT being forwarded on to the original URL.

Is this possible? I know, from an SEO standpoint this is not ideal, but we are creating several groups of pages (sub-sites) and several of the sub-pages need to have the same content and it will be tedious to edit them one-by-one.

Is the only option here to create and embed blocks on the pages so that the content is unified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the core module [path](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/path) you can do this:

> **Tips about URL aliases**
>
> Although it is possible to assign the same internal URL to multiple
>   aliases, this is generally not a good idea for search engine rankings;
>   Google, for example, penalises your site by dropping its rank if
>   Google thinks that you are publishing duplicate content under multiple
>   URLs (a form of web spamming).

I just tried to add 3 aliases on the same `node/123` and it works without any problem. Go to `Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases` or directly to `admin/config/search/path` to add a new alias and see the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks tostinni - but the issue with this is that it still redirects to the original content. Say you have an alias in a menu on Site A - it will take you to Site B where the original content resides and you'll lose your navigation from Site A. Not what we want to occur.

Comment: Core Drupal aliases don't do redirect, so you will stay on the same URL. In your question you didn't mention aliases between two different sites or domains.

Comment: Same domain, same site - different 'sub sites' with different menus. We can't have someone click on a link which is aliased and be taken off to a different menu because that's where the original content lives.

Comment: Is the problem that when you type in example.com/this-posts-title-is-a-nice-path, it gets redirected to example.com/node/2377 which then has different menus? Or is the problem that the URL stays, but the context of the page changes, so that you see different menus and blocks and so forth?

Answer (score 0):

The [front](http://drupal.org/project/front) module has an "alias" option that does that for the homepage. You might be able to "extend" that module.